# How to call native (Android) function from PlayN?

Tags: android, ios, native, playn

Is it possible to call "native" platform-specific Java code from PlayN game? For example launch an external (Android and iOS) activity as response to button click? Can you link me to some demo how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you need to make an interface to call your native code; we did this to implement ads on our game, [Admob Support in PlayN](http://setfalse.blogspot.com/) you can check how we did it and maybe it can help you.

Comment: Great! Your blog also answers other question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636688/embedding-playn-game-into-android-activity so you can post some answer there too and I can accept it then. I'm just curious how you've managed to get overridden ``onCreate()`` method working? ``AndroidGL20`` instance is shared also in some attributes of ``AndroidPlatform`` created in super's ``onCreate()``. When I tried to override ``onCreate()`` similar way it was crashing because of that. What version of PlayN are you using?

Comment: Also, from the blog is not apparent how you've implemented and connected iOS native code in C# to its Java PlayN interface. For Android is pretty straightforward.