# Embedding PlayN game into Android activity

Tags: java, android, playn

Is it somehow possible to embed PlayN game view within Android activity with custom layout? I mean any way because, looking at the PlayN code, it apparently is not supported yet. Have anyone tried to hack this already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are now developing this feature. Actually we are trying to deploy PlayN into an Android Fragment, what offer us to insert our Fragment with PlayN game into any Activity with any layout.
Here is our fork of PlayN: https://github.com/FinamTrade/playn
please see GameInAndroidFragment branch.